# filter columns of a dataframe based on a vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with multiple columns, to which I calculate the median by column and then filter by the rows that are greater than its median. My question is there is some way to create a shorter code.

**Note:** The filter I need always meets the condition for Xi> xi.

```
set.seed(123)
df = data.frame(replicate(10,sample(1:10,1000,rep=TRUE)))
x <- sapply(df,median)
library(dplyr)
filter(df, X1 > x[1], X2 > x[2], X3 > x[3], X4 > x[4], X5  > x[5], 
           X6 > x[6], X7 > x[7], X8 > x[8], X9 > x[9], X10 > x[10])
```

Expected output

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1  8 10  7  9  8  6 10  8  8   9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way -

```
filter(df, apply(df, 1, function(a) all(a > x)))

  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1  8 10  7  9  8  6 10  8  8   9
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map2(df, x , `>`) %>%
     reduce(`&`) %>% 
     magrittr::extract(df, .,)
#    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
#930  8 10  7  9  8  6 10  8  8   9
```